# Google map fatal exception on android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on a project on android. One of the applications is to show the google map, and pin point some locations. (It works at first, showing all the pins and the map, but after a while, it crashes and I got this error.

Build gradle:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sptd.fleetbasic"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.7
        sourceCompatibility 1.7
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.+'
    implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:4.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
/*    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'*/
}
```

Error:

```html
--------- beginning of crash
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-ula-1
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.sptd.fleetbasic, PID: 5239
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'java.lang.Object sq.a(int, java.lang.Object)' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg' (declaration of 'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg' appears in /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/MapsDynamite.apk)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366044@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):28)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-ula-1
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.sptd.fleetbasic, PID: 5239
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'java.lang.Object sq.a(int, java.lang.Object)' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg' (declaration of 'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg' appears in /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/MapsDynamite.apk)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366044@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):28)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-ula-1
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.sptd.fleetbasic, PID: 5239
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'java.lang.Object sq.a(int, java.lang.Object)' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg' (declaration of 'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg' appears in /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/MapsDynamite.apk)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366044@14.3.66 (040300-213742215):28)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-14 15:09:10.649  5239  5320 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-14 15:09:10.708  5239  5320 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 5239 SIG: 9
11-14 15:09:10.708  5239  5320 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 5239 SIG: 9
11-14 15:09:10.708  5239  5320 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 5239 SIG: 9
11-14 15:09:10.708  5239  5320 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 5239 SIG: 9
```

My device is an android 6.0. Anyone knows how to solve this?

### Edited:

Here is the code of the fragment about showing the google map and the location pin.
I found that the error usually occurs after I refreshed method (called every few minutes )...(For the first few times it successfully removed the old pins and add new markers on the map, but returns to an error afterwards)..

```html
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class LocationFragment extends Fragment implements DataProvider.locationsAvailable {

    DataProvider dp;
    Info info;
    int sectionNo;
    MapView UnitsMapView;
    SearchView locationSearchView;
    TextView searchErrTV;
    LinearLayout searchError;

    List<Location> locations;
    Marker searchMarker;
    LatLng searchLatLng;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    final private String TAG = "Location";

    public LocationFragment() {
    }

    public static LocationFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, DataProvider dp, Info info) {
        LocationFragment fragment = new LocationFragment();
        fragment.sectionNo = sectionNumber;
        fragment.dp = dp;
        fragment.info = info;
        fragment.locations = new ArrayList<>();
        return fragment;
    }

    //get refreshed location list from DataProvider and display on map with markers
    public void refreshed(List<Location> list) {
        locations.clear();
        locations = list;
        Log.d(TAG, "received from DP: " + locations.toString());
        if (locations != null) {
            if (googleMap != null) {
                googleMap.clear();
                LatLng Home = new LatLng(xxxx , xxxx);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Home));
                for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {
                    Location location_tmp = locations.get(i);
                    if (location_tmp.getlocationAvail()) {
                        LatLng unit_tmp = new LatLng(location_tmp.getLatitude(), location_tmp.getLongitude());
                        
                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(unit_tmp).title(location_tmp.getUnit().getName())
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizeMapIcons("logo_pin", 40, 45))));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap resizeMapIcons(String iconName,int width, int height){
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),getResources().getIdentifier(iconName, "drawable", ManageActivity.PACKAGE_NAME));
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, width, height, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);

        searchErrTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchErrTV);
        searchError =(LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.SearchErr);

        //a search function for searching specific unit's location
        locationSearchView = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.locationSearchView);
        locationSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        //for changing text size of the search view as not responsive in xml
        LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) locationSearchView.getChildAt(0);
        LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout1.getChildAt(2);
        LinearLayout linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.getChildAt(1);
        AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) linearLayout3.getChildAt(0);
        autoComplete.setTextSize(19);

        final int searchCloseButtonId = locationSearchView.getContext().getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
        ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) this.locationSearchView.findViewById(searchCloseButtonId);
        // Set on click listener for the close (cross symbol) button
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (searchMarker != null) {
                    searchMarker.remove();
                }
                searchError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                locationSearchView.setQuery("", false);
                locationSearchView.clearFocus();
            }
        });

        locationSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //to let visibility gone again in case user didn't press close button
                searchError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                boolean unitFound = false;
                for(int i=0; i<locations.size(); i++) {

                    if ((locations.get(i).getUnit() != null) && (query.matches("^.*\\d+.*$"))){

                        if (locations.get(i).getUnit().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(query) ||
                                Integer.parseInt(locations.get(i).getUnit().getName().replaceAll("\\D+",""))
                                        == ( Integer.parseInt(query.replaceAll("\\D+",""))) ){
                            unitFound = true;
                            if (searchMarker != null) {
                                searchMarker.remove();
                            }

                            if (locations.get(i).getlocationAvail()) {
                                searchLatLng = new LatLng(locations.get(i).getLatitude(), locations.get(i).getLongitude());
/*                                searchMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(searchLatLng).title(locations.get(i).getUnit().getName())
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizeMapIcons("sptd_logo_pin", 180, 190))));*/
                                searchMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(searchLatLng).title(locations.get(i).getUnit().getName())
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizeMapIcons("ogo_pin", 40, 45))));
                                searchMarker.showInfoWindow();
                                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(searchLatLng).zoom(18).build();
                                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                            } else {
                                searchErrTV.setText(R.string.locationErrNoCrumb);
                                searchError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (unitFound == false){
                    searchErrTV.setText(R.string.locationErrNoUnit);
                    searchError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        dp.locationsListener = this;
        dp.refresh(DataProvider.LOCATIONS);
        dp.refresh(DataProvider.UNITS);

        UnitsMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.UnitsMapView);
        UnitsMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UnitsMapView.onResume();

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        UnitsMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;

                LatLng Home = new LatLng(22.3900875 , 114.208085);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Home));

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(Home).zoom(12).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        UnitsMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        UnitsMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        UnitsMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        UnitsMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

Another thing is that, the device I'm using is probably a rooted one, could that be a problem too?

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 0):

try to put android:hardwareAccelerated="true" on manifest activity tag

Please add this permission to manifest if you do not included

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Also include this item to application tag in manifest:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_ver sion" />
```

And include this for opengl in manufest as well

```
<uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: please check have you added opengl , version and API key as well?

Comment: I didn't add opengl..
API key should be okay, since I have used it on another application

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please apply those item and see if the problem will be solved.